# Is it on topic here for questions not about specific code but rather how to manage the code?

Tags: discussion, scope

Title explains it: I want to ask a question about maintaining branches of a single project and I'm not sure if it's on topic. If not, is there anywhere that it would be on topic?

Comment: CR reviews the code itself, not the project architecture, not project management. Branches as in *source control*? Hard to tell without reading minds, but I believe management strategies for branching would be on-topic on [softwareengineering.se] (though you *will* want to double-check that)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Off-topic

Code Review requires code. If there is no code then there is nothing we can work off to improve, and so there's no way for us to help.

---

It should be noted that even if you have 'managing code' (via GNU make or Invoke), you may not get the answer you're looking for as we'll try to make *that* code better. But we may not necessarily make your management any better.